# vector subscript out of range :(

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2015

So I'm a relatively new c++ programmer. I just made this code as a part of an object-oriented tic-tac-toe I'm working on. It's in Visual Studio Community 2015 and when the code is supposed to check for a winner, I get the error "vector subscript out of range". It sucks, it sucks.

```
int Board::Win_Check()
{
    int ar[8][3] = {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7, 8 },
        { 0, 3, 6 },
        { 1, 4, 7 },
        { 2, 5, 8 },
        { 0, 4, 8 },
        { 2, 4, 6 } };

    int winner1 = 0;
    int winner2 = 0;

    bool winner1won = false;
    bool winner2won = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            if (m_board[ar[i][j]] == 'X')
            {
                ++winner1;
            }
            else if (m_board[ar[i][j]] == 'Y')
            {
                ++winner2;
            }

            if (winner1 != 3)
            {
                winner1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                winner1won = true;
            }

            if (winner2 != 3)
            {
                winner2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                winner2won = true;
            }
        }
    }

    int return_type;

    if (winner1won == true)
    {
        return_type = 1;
    }
    else if (winner2won == true)
    {
        return_type = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return_type = 0;
    }

    return return_type;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to provide more information to where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously going out of range with your indices here

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
```

should be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                  // ^
```

as the array was declared

```
int ar[8][3] = {
    // ^
```

Comment: One of the reasons why, at any rate. Magic Numbers build weak teeth and bones several ways. Just say no to Magic Numbers.